# Problem with typeorm nested entity( Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'getEntityValue' )

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am creating a `nestjs` project with `typeorm` and `postgresql`. Here I am creating a user entity.

My entity will be like

```
{
    email: string,
    name: string,
    avatar: {
        public_key: string;
        url: string;
    }
}
```

In avatar column I need to add a object with `public_key` and `url`.

I create two `entity` like this-

```
@Entity()
class Avatar {
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    public_key: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    url: string;
}

@Entity()
@Tree("closure-table")
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    userName: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    email: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    firstName: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false })
    lastName: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: false, select: false })
    password: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true })
    socket_id: string;
    @Column({ type: "text", nullable: true, select: false })
    otp: string;
    @TreeChildren()
    avatar: Avatar;
    @Column({ type: "boolean", default: false, nullable: false })
    is_verify: boolean;
    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;

    //Before Insert Injection
    @BeforeInsert()
    createUserName() {
        this.userName = uniqid.time()
    }
}
```

Here I use `closure-table` to do nested `avatar` entity

Here I write

```
 @TreeChildren()
 avatar: Avatar;
```

For nesting `Avatar` Entity

Then in my controller I try to create my first data-

```
const result = await this.userRepository.create({
    ...userInput,
    otp: secret.base32,
    password: passwordHash,
});
await this.userRepository.save(result)
```

Note: avatar field is not required. Avatar field will be add when user update their profile. Here I only create first user data.

But I am getting this error-

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getEntityValue')`

Please help me.

//Updated

```
import { InputType, Field } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { IsEmail, IsString, MinLength, IsNotEmpty, MaxLength, Matches } from "class-validator";

@InputType()
export class UserInput {
    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @IsString()
    @IsEmail()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    email: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    firstName: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    lastName: string;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: false })
    @IsString()
    @MinLength(8)
    @MaxLength(20)
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @Matches(/^.*(?=.{4,10})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$/, { message: "password too weak" })
    password: string
}
```

Comment: Can you share the ```userInput``` here?

Comment: Hello, @vicki, I updated my questions with `userInput`